# ComboBox SelectedItem only updates after first time

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

When i do something that the selected item changed,there is some problem. ie, when the first time , it's not working correctly...then after no problem...Any idea?

View model:

```
public ObservableCollection<SomeType> Items { get; set; } // Implement 
public SomeType Item { get; set; } // INotifyPropertyChanged here
```

View:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item}" />
```

Then property

```
  public SomeType Item 
 {
  get { return item; }
  set
  {
    if (item != value)
    {
        item = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Item");
        // New item has been selected. Do something here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe showing some code would help

Comment: @Jinesh, you *did* implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your view model, didn't you? My `Implement INotifyPropertyChanged here` comment wasn't there for fun.

Comment: I'm confused. Title says it only updates the first time, but message says it updates every time *except* for the first time. Which is it? And which way are you making the update and expecting the change? i.e. are you saying that using the UI and selecting an item from the combo is not setting the VM `Item` property, or that changing the VM `Item` property is not updating the UI?

Comment: @Sheridan,did you mean 
        public ObservableCollection<SomeType> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _Items;
            }

            set
            {
                _Items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Items");
            }
        }                             I know it is not fun

Comment: @Mashton, that was my bad... I edited the title from something that described the question even less... I'll fix it now. Apologies everyone. And Jinesh, yes I did mean that, good.

Comment: But,it's not working....

Comment: try to set binding mode to two-way `SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay}"`?

Comment: Maybe some focus weirdness going on? Try setting UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged.

Comment: I am doing this all...but no change

Comment: @JineshG Which way are you making the update and expecting the change? i.e. are you saying that using the UI and selecting an item from the combo is not setting the VM Item property, or that changing the VM Item property is not updating the UI? You also have two definitions for `Item` in your code above: one with the automatic get/set and the other with the complete INotifyPropertyChanged setter. Remove the one that isn't being used any more to make the question cleaner.

Comment: @har07, the default `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` options defined in the [`Selector.SelectedItem` Property] includes the `BindsTwoWayByDefault` enumeration... that means that it binds `TwoWay` by default.

Comment: Are you sure about that your first item is already present in ItemSource?